# How to add up a certain group of number in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop

Hey so I have function that needs to add up a certain number of even numbers in an array based off user input. Here's my approach so far:

function call:

```
cout << "The sum of the first " << userSum << " even numbers is: " << 
SumEvens(list,   SIZE,   userSum);
```

function definition:

```
int SumEvens(int arr[], const int size, int evensAdd)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++){       
        for (int j = 0; j <= evensAdd; j++){
            if (arr[i] % 2 == 0)
                sum += arr[i];
        } 
   }
return sum;
}
```

I'm Not sure if i need the double for loop here, but it seems necessary so that i can go through every number and then only select the ones that i need.

Now whenever I run this program and tell it to add up the numbers it spits out garbage, so I was seeing if you guys could point out any glaring flaws in the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is incorrect:

```
int SumEvens(int arr[], const int size, int evensAdd)
{
   for(int i= 0; i < size; i++){
     std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << size << " " << evensAdd << std::endl;



  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++){       
         if(evensAdd==0) return sum
         if (arr[i] % 2 == 0){
              sum += arr[i];
              evensAdd--;
         }
      } 
  }
return sum;
}
```

This doesn't break on `evenAdd > size`

Comment: i just tried that and it gave me the same garbage output... would that mean it's my call messing me up?

Comment: This would either indicate you have not set the values in your `array` properly which I think is the case. Or `size` is not set correctly

Comment: how do you mean? i currently have the user fill in the array if those are the values you are talking about.    size is just a constant passed into the function so im not sure what you mean by saying its not set correctly.

Comment: Do me a favor and add the things that I added to my edit. Then show me the inputs. (The print statements so I can see the inputs to the function)

Comment: hey it worked, Virtual Studio for some reason wont update the code in real time sometimes. Thanks!